# How to real-time update while .txt file(Notepad) is open?

Tags: c#, windows, file

I have a program that writes data to a `.txt` file(Notepad) in a temporary location. This program changes the value and runs it multiple times. Unfortunately, each time that happens, you have to close and reopen the `.txt` file.

Is there any way to solve this?

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new Client();
        var service = new Service();
        client.Operation(service);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Client
{
    public void Operation(IService service)
    {
        service.Write("Hello C# world");
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface IService
{
    public void Write(string message);
}
```

```cs
public class Service : IService
{
    private const string Path = @"C:\Temp/tempFile.txt";
    
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(Path);
        writer.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

The reason we need this method is for learning purposes.

To practice the decorator pattern, I'm writing a temporary program that supports compression and encryption. I use a `.txt` file because it's really simple and only needed.

It doesn't have to be a `.txt` file, as you just need to visually verify it.

Comment: If a process have a file open with write access it will always block that instance of the file. No other process can edit that file until the first process remove it's lock on the file.

Comment: Maybe you should use a database instead?

Comment: Who or what has to "close and reopen the .txt file"? E.g. Sublime Text will notice if a file has been updated by another process, but Notepad won't.

Comment: @Franck Oh, I just found it impossible

Comment: @AKX The .txt file is just notepad turned on on my computer.

Comment: Actually you can use shared locks for a file but that is quite low level operation. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex IMHO, a database is the way to go.

Comment: @CetinBasoz It is a pity that more energy is consumed to solve simple hassles.

Comment: It is still simple if you use a database. What makes it a hassle is you are trying to use plain txt file. And you didn't really explain what purpose could it have.

Comment: Um, @IsakGo, what does "The .txt file is just notepad turned on on my computer." mean? As I explained, Notepad doesn't check whether the file has changed. Other, more civilized editors do. On UNIX systems, `tail -f` works too, and updates the file in real-time.

Comment: @Franck That's irrelevant here – you can see the streamwriter for the path is open exactly for the `Write` invocation.

Comment: @CetinBasoz As you said, I've added the necessary reason...

Comment: I see, just for learning purposes, you can then also use a simplier code as File.WriteAllLines( filename, linesCollection). For a real use case maybe you are trying to reinvent a logger.

Comment: @AKX Sorry for the weird explanation. To elaborate more on what I mean, the `.txt` file is open in `Windows`, and I build and run the program several times in `Rider`.

Comment: @CetinBasoz If I really need this feature, I'll use the database as you advised :)

Comment: @IsakGo I'm quite sure you don't have the file "open in Windows", but in some program. If that program is e.g. Notepad, it won't update the view if the file changes on disk. Other programs, such as the Rider IDE, will. (In fact Rider would ask whether you want to keep any changes you'd made if it notices the file has changed on disk; if you haven't made any changes, it just refreshes it.)

Comment: You can also write a "text file viewer" program that continuously watches for whether a given path has updated, and if so, it rereads it. Once again, e.g. Notepad doesn't do that.

Comment: @AKX Ah... I foolishly had the stereotype that `.txt` was a Notepad. The `.txt` I was talking about is Notepad. We will update the post.

Comment: @IsakGo "`.txt` is a Notepad" does not make sense and it feels like there's a fundamental misunderstanding there. `.txt` is a common _file extension_ for plain-text files. Notepad is a basic program that can read and write plain-text files (in various encodings, but let's skim over that for now). You can open any file with Notepad to see how it attempts to interpret it as a plain-text file.

Comment: Furthermore, "a program that supports compression and encryption. I use a .txt file because it's really simple and only needed." -- once you compress and/or encrypt some data, it's quite certainly not plain text any more and `.txt` wouldn't be a suitable extension.

Comment: @AKX I realize once gain that my knowledge is wrong and lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the file just fine with your code. (You can verify that by looking at the file's size in File Explorer when you write into it.)

It's just that Notepad, the program you're viewing it with, isn't smart enough to check whether the file has updated on disk and refresh its view of it accordingly.

You can use an alternative editor, such as Notepad++, Sublime Text, Visual Studio Code, any JetBrains IDE, whatever, that *is* smart enough to check whether the file should be refreshed.

You could also write your *own* program to re-read and show the contents of the file in real-time.

Comment: Thanks for all of your time, I was able to solve the problem :D